Classical solution to a semi-linear parabolic PDE
Let $\Omega\subset \mathbb R^d$ be convex and compact with regular boundary $\partial\Omega$, where $d\ge 2$. Consider the boundary problem on $I\times \Omega$, for $I=(0,T)$ or $I=\mathbb R_+$,
$$\partial_t u + \Delta u -K |\nabla u|+1=0 \quad\mbox{and}\quad u|_{I\times \partial\Omega}\equiv 0,$$
where $K : I\times \Omega\to \mathbb R_+$ is bounded. When $I=(0,T)$, one has the terminal condition
$$u(T,\cdot)=g,$$
where $g:\Omega\to \mathbb R_+$ is continuous and bounded. It is known that both problems admit a weak solution (whose definition can be specified if needed), and in particular the weak solution is unique for $I=(0,T)$.
Under which conditions on $K, g$ (maybe $\Omega$), there exists a classical solution to the above problems?
Any answer or reference is highly appreciated.
